# BASH version version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) breaks script that works on version 4.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Tags: linux, bash

This script works on Fedora 20:

```
#!/bin/bash
# DRE 2015 - Thinking, Realizing, Reacting
# this version reads files of a certain .suffix passed as arg $1
if [ "$1" == "-h" ] ; then
    echo "remove_n_file removes files of type (arg1) every nth (arg2) from a directory"
    exit
else
    :
fi

x=0
y=0
n=$2
echo $n
FILES=./*.$1        # BASH resolves variable for you
for  f in $FILES
do
    echo $f     # iterates through and echoes 
    ((x++))         # postincrements counter for all type file
    if ((x%n == 0))  ;  then  # test for file increment and execute
        rm -f "$f"   # you need to quote filename variable to get name in proper format to rm command
        ((y++))     
    else 
        :
    fi
done
echo files count: "$x"
echo files removed : "$y"
```

But it fails with errors on Ubuntu 14.10 with version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

It fails and complains of:

> x++: not found
>   x%n: not found

What change was made to BASH variables in the later release to break functionality?

Comment: Does `(( x += 1 ))` and `(( x % n == 0 ))` work?  Sometimes whitespace matters.

Comment: The syntax is fine. Could it be that your `bash` is soft-linked to your `shell`? That is, can you check if it is in fact running under bash and not in shell?

Comment: Or perhaps you're invoking the script with the `sh` command instead of just running it.

Comment: Hello,  thanks for comments. Spacing math did not work.

Comment: Fixed;  I removed sh from command line and also the downloaded file was not executable. Changed permissions and it worked.  I had downloaded from Google Drive to make sure it works.  Thanks for help!